# What does the phrase 「学問に励む」 means in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words

This is a quote from a book.

> 差が生まれるのは、学問に励んだのか励まなかったのか。そこに違いが生じてくる、と綴ってある。

What does 「学問に励む」 mean?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?  eg  https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/"学問に励" / https://jisho.org/search/励む

Comment: @Chocolate Yes I checked. But my English is not good and I only recently started studying Japanese, so I wasn't exactly sure what the phrase means. Especially the exact meaning of 学問 in the sentence. And thank you for the links. I knew Jisho, but Weblio looks good as well.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you lack English skill...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply, it means "**study hard**."

- 学問⇒**study**.
- に⇒**at**, **on**, **to** and etc.
- 励む⇒**make an    effort**.

So the phrase directly means "make an effort at studying" or "focus on studying."